# How to set up a test for a specific php function

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, tdd, phpunit

Can anyone please help me set up an unit-test for this php code, ive been trying and haven't found a solution yet. I have recieved this code from the developer-team and Im supposed to create unit-tests for it any ideas on how to go about this?

```
function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
   // Get timestamp of current time
   $now = time();
   // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
   $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60); 

   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) { `enter code here`
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id); 
      // Execute the prepared query.
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      // If there has been more than 5 failed logins
      if($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a test is touching the database (or the network, the file system or any other external service) it is not a unit test. Asides from any definition, testing through the DB is slow and error prone. Mocking is almost too easy in dynamic languages, yet many people still test business logic through the DB. I am usually not a fan of posting complete solutions to a question. In this case I feel the need to do so to prove that it is actually quite easy, especially in the sitution described in the question.

```
class CheckBruteTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function test_checkbrute__some_user__calls_db_and_statement_with_correct_params() {
        $expected_user_id = 23;
        $statement_mock = $this->getMock('StatementIface', array());
        $statement_mock->expects($this->once())->method('bind_param')
            ->with($this->equalTo('i'), $this->equalTo($expected_user_id));
        $statement_mock->expects($this->once())->method('execute');
        $statement_mock->expects($this->once())->method('store_result');

        $db_mock = $this->getMock('DbIface', array());
        $time_ignoring_the_last_two_decimals = floor((time() - 2 * 60 * 60) / 100);
        $db_mock->expects($this->once())->method('prepare')
            ->with($this->stringStartsWith("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$time_ignoring_the_last_two_decimals"))
            ->will($this->returnValue($statement_mock));

        checkbrute($expected_user_id, $db_mock);
    }

    public function test_checkbrute__more_then_five__return_true() {
        $statement_mock = $this->getMock('StatementIface', array());
        $statement_mock->num_rows = 6;
        $db_mock = $this->getMock('DbIface', array());
        $db_mock->expects($this->once())->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue($statement_mock));

        $result = checkbrute(1, $db_mock);

        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }

    public function test_checkbrute__less_or_equal_then_five__return_false() {
        $statement_mock = $this->getMock('StatementIface', array());
        $statement_mock->num_rows = 5;
        $db_mock = $this->getMock('DbIface', array());
        $db_mock->expects($this->once())->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue($statement_mock));

        $result = checkbrute(1, $db_mock);

        $this->assertFalse($result);
    }
}
interface DbIface {
    public function prepare($query);
}
abstract class StatementIface {
    public abstract function bind_param($i, $user_id);
    public abstract function execute();
    public abstract function store_result();
    public $num_rows;
}
```

Since I do not know the specification of the function I can only derive it from the code.

In the first test case I only check through the mocks for the DB and the statement if the code is actually calling these services as expected. Most importantly it checks if the correct user ID is passed to the statement and if the correct time constraint is used. The time check is rather hacky, but that is what you get, if you call services like `time()` directly in your business code.

The second test case forces the number of attempted logins to be 6 and asserts if the function returns `true`.

The third test case forces the number of attempted logins to be 5 and asserts if the function returns `false`.

This covers (almost) all of the code paths in the function. Only one code path is left out: If `$mysqli->prepare()` return null or any other value that evaluates to `false` the whole if-block is bypassed and returns null implicitly. I don't know if that is on purpose. Code should make something like that explicit.

For mocking reasons I created the little interface and the little abstract class. They are only needed in the context of the tests. One could also implement custom mock classes for the `$mysqli` parameter and the return value of `$mysqli->prepare()`, but I prefer to use automatic mocks.

Some additional notes, that have nothing to do with the solution:

- Unit Tests are developer tests and should be written by the developers themselves, not some poor tester. Testers write acceptance and regression tests.
- The "hackiness" of the test cases shows why writing tests after the fact is much harder. Had the devs written the code TDD style, the code AND the test would have been much cleaner.
- The design of the checkbrute function is rather suboptimal:

  - 'checkbrute' is a bad name. It is not really telling its story.
  - It is mixing business code with DB access. The calculation of the time constraint is business code as well as the check for `>5`. The code in between is DB code and belongs in its own function/class/whatever.
  - Magic numbers. Please use constants for magic numbers like the 2h value and the maximum number of login attempts.

Answer (score -1):

A unit test is simple to create : it puts data in database (with inserts), and checks if the function's return is good on these data. Then,when the test is done, it deletes the data.

Here, you must insert values in login_attempts, for exemple :

```
INSERT login_attempts(user_id, time, ...) VALUES (12, 1367849298)
```

and then check the return value of your function.

Comment: Where do i run this code? And do you know any good tutorials or website that can help me learn this.

Comment: You can run this code wherever you want ! Check this link : http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html. I found it by searching "php unit test" on Google... Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Do you know how to test functions that don't have a class? I have been given a file that has very many functions that I would like to unit-test but I can't seem to get it to work without using classes. Any ideas how to solve this without implementing classes?

Comment: Can you please write a working unit-test for the code i pasted so i can learn how it works.

Comment: $deity is killing a kitten every time you use "unit test" and "database" in the same sentence.